# Where can I find the XAML for XamlControlsResources?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

We recently updated the styling of our app to use WinUI 2.x and while we generally like the changes we have found areas that look terrible and will require overriding the defaults. I looked for a file that would have the default XAML implementation/definitions associated with the new styles, something similar to what's in the generic.xaml file, but I was not able to find it. I would appreciate someone pointing me to this file, if it exists.

~Rich

Comment: For which control(s) are you trying to fint the default template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the WinUI 2 controls and the XAML templates are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/aee08507a957796e475e9c7cfd0d1291a526a73c/dev).

For example, [DropDownButton.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/aee08507a957796e475e9c7cfd0d1291a526a73c/dev/DropDownButton/DropDownButton.xaml).

Comment: I was not aware of that resource, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction. For controls not listed there (e.g. Button or GridView or ContentDialog) whose layout and appearance were impacted when we switched to WinUI, is there some other reference that either has the latest XAML or has a description of how the controls changed?

Comment: So, for example, it is now really hard to see the selected GridView item using the default styling. The gray border around the selected item is very hard to distinguish from the background container, especially in Dark Mode, so it looks like we will need to either change the page color or adjust the selection border. But before I started making changes I was hoping to see the default XAML

Comment: @RichS You could check this file- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.19041.0\Generic\generic.xaml`. It contains all the templates of UWP controls. You could find other templates like buttons there.

Comment: @RichS: The styles for the built-in controls such as `Button` can be found in the [CommonStyles](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/main/dev/CommonStyles) folder.