# How to override default WinUI 2.x styles in Blend?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821516/where-can-i-find-the-xaml-for-xamlcontrolsresources/68822487) I had asked where to find the default styles for the WinUI 2.x controls, and was pointed to the appropriate repository in GitHub where those could be found. Thanks! However, what I really want is to be able to override some of the styles. I was expecting that I would be able to do so in Blend, but I have not been able to figure out how to do that.

For example, when I load my project in Blend and then try to edit the templates for the ContentDialog, I am offered the option to apply an existing style, but not to create a new one. I was expecting I could create a copy, which would give me the default styling as a starting point and allow me to make the small modifications I require. Regarding buttons, I was able to edit a copy of the template, but that only gave me access to the ControlTemplate where I want access to the equivalent of DefaultButtonStyle.

It has been a while since I've used Blend, so perhaps I am mis-remembering how the tool works. But in previous versions of our app I was able to generate resources that included the full styling of the controls that I was using, such as buttons and content dialogs. Can I do the same for our current app that uses WinUI 2.x? If so, how? And if not, what are my alternatives? I have considered copying the default templates I am interested in into the resources of my project and making modifications that way, but I am hopeful that there is a better way.

Rich

Comment: Not familiar with Blend, but why not do it in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am offered the option to apply an existing style, but not to create a new one

This is expected. For example, both the Visual Studio or the Blend for Visual Studio can't directly create a default DropDownButton style of WinUI. You need to manually copy the WinUI style from Github and put the style in your XAML.

For native UWP controls, you could just generate a copy of the style automatically.

Comment: How does generating a copy of the style automatically work?